# Choose CORS Access-Control-Max-Age value

Tags: api, http, cors, aws-api-gateway, api-design

My API is configured to cache CORS preflight request by using the HTTP header `Access-Control-Max-Age`. The value is set to 600 seconds. I chose this value because [according to Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age) documentation this is the maximum allowed by Chrome.

> Maximum number of seconds the results can be cached.
>   Firefox caps this at 24 hours (86400 seconds) and Chromium at 10 minutes (600 seconds). Chromium also specifies a default value of 5
>   seconds.
>   A value of -1 will disable caching, requiring a preflight OPTIONS check for all calls.

What is a recommended `Access-Control-Max-Age` value and how to choose it?

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age

> Firefox caps this at 24 hours (86400 seconds).
> Chromium (prior to v76) caps at 10 minutes (600 seconds).
> Chromium (starting in v76) caps at 2 hours (7200 seconds).
> Chromium also specifies a default value of 5 seconds.

We use 86400 seconds.